# Solving a vector differential equation with absolute values

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors

I need to solve $$\frac{d\mathbf{r_c}}{dt}=kv\frac{\mathbf{r_s}-\mathbf{r_c}}{|\mathbf{r_s}-\mathbf{r_c}|}$$ where $\mathbf{r_s}=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}0\\v\end{array}\right]t$ and at $t=0$, $\mathbf{r_c}=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}a\\0\end{array}\right]$.

How?

Answer (score 1):

Define $$\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_c-\mathbf{r}_s$$ then your system is

$$\dot{\mathbf{r}}=-kv\hat{r} - \dot{\mathbf{r}_s} $$

Note: welcome to MSE. When asking questions, you should always show what you did and where you got stuck.

Comment: How can you simplify it to $\dot{r}=-kv$ when $r \neq r_{c}$ and $r_{s}$ depends on time?

Comment: Didn’t notice the time dependence earlier. I have updated it.  Just time-differentiate the first equation in the answer to get the second. Note that $\dot{\mathbf{r}_s}$ is just a constant vector.

Comment: I am still not sure how to solve this. How do you deal with the unit vector? If it was not a unit vector and was equal to $\mathbf{r}$ then you could solve it as normal.